# Функция с макросом обработки переменного числа параметров в Си

Tags: c, макросы

Задача: Задано n чисел, найти сумму всех чисел, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя - единицу и самого себя. Решить задачу, используя макросы обработки переменного числа параметров.
Я написал код, который работает корректно, но как мне изменить его, чтобы в нем использовались макросы обработки переменного числа.

```
int Dell(int number,...){
int sum = 0;
int* ptr = &number+1;
for(int i = 1; i < number+1;i++){
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 2; j < *ptr;j++){
        if(*ptr % j == 0){
            break;
        }
        count++;
        if(count == (*ptr) -2){
            sum += *ptr;
        }
    }
    (ptr++);
}
return sum;}
```

Comment: Вы написали непереносимый код. Читайте https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg - там есть пример кода, вам его только чуть дописать. Кстати, к чему это все многословие *сумму всех чисел, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя - единицу и самого себя* вместо ясного "сумму всех простых чисел"? :)

Comment: Благодарю, смог разобраться в чем до этого была ошибка.

Comment: Этот код не работает, разыменование указателя `ptr` приводит к неопределенному поведению.